# WPF textbox with image

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, textbox, passwordbox

I'm doing a WPF login interface. In my login panel, I have one login `TextBox` and a `PasswordBox`. As what shown in the first image below, there is a little human logo in the login textbox and a lock in the password box. I set the image into the textbox background, and then when i try to insert some word into the login box, the words will overide the human logo(image B). Any advice to make it right?

My XAML:

```
 <TextBox Width="380" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Foreground="WhiteSmoke" BorderBrush="Transparent" >
     <TextBox.Background>
       <ImageBrush ImageSource="/icon/user_login.png" AlignmentX="Left" Stretch="None"></ImageBrush>
     </TextBox.Background>
 </TextBox>
```

Image A:

[image]

Image B:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My suggestion is that you replace each of the `Textbox's` with a `DockPanel`. In which they each have an `Image` as the left-most item and a `Textbox` as the right most. Then set the images to User and Lock respectively. Then set the backgrounds of the `Textbox` and `Images` to transparent. You can then set whatever styling you want on the `DockPanel`.

EDIT 1 - Copy paste from working example

Code:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Button BorderThickness="0" DockPanel.Dock="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="28" Width="23">
         <DynamicResource ResourceKey="SearchBar"/>
    </Button> 'This is a button, because I have a custom Style which I am using which makes all the borders go away. And also because I use it to clear the field.
    <TextBox Text="Search..." FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Image:

[image]

By not setting the `DockPanel.Dock` property on the second item, I am telling it to stretch across the rest of the `DockPanel`. Any other queries, please let me know. If you copy paste the above, it might not look the same, due to me cutting out irrelevant parts.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="65,24,71,11" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Image Source="/SDPI;component/Image/Profile.png"/>
                            <toolkit:WatermarkTextBox Grid.Row="1" FontSize="16">
                                <toolkit:WatermarkTextBox.Watermark>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Text="Username" FontSize="15" Margin="4,0,0,0" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </toolkit:WatermarkTextBox.Watermark>
                            </toolkit:WatermarkTextBox>
                        </DockPanel>
```

Comment: WatermarkTextBox comes from the Extended WPF Toolkit™ Community Edition: https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WatermarkTextBox&referringTitle=Home