# how to separate the background image in wpf textbox?

Tags: wpf, image, textbox

I am new to WPF. In my project i have tried user name textbox box with usericon.

My XAML Code:-

```
> <TextBox Height="30" Width="180" Margin="67,123,256,158">
>             <TextBox.Background>
>                 <ImageBrush  ImageSource="Images/User.png" Stretch="None" AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Center" />
>             </TextBox.Background>
>         </TextBox>
```

[image]

But when i type the user name, text-box cursor starts from the left end, two or three letters are not visible and its looking ugly.  (see the image) How i can separate this background image in textbox.

Edit 1-

```
>  <Canvas>
>         <DockPanel Canvas.Left="115" Canvas.Top="64">
>             <Button BorderThickness="0" DockPanel.Dock="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="28" Width="23">
>                 <Button.Background>
>                     <ImageBrush  ImageSource="Images/User.png" Stretch="None" AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Center" />
>                 </Button.Background>
>             </Button>
>             <TextBox Height="28" Width="115" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent"/>
>         </DockPanel>
>         </Canvas>
```

[image]

I have tried as per the suggestion. But the problem is the button and text box are shows separate. It not look like user icon in texbox. And when i move the cursor to button, the usericon has invisible. help me to improve my code..

EDIT 2 With Answer:-

Add the below code in grid resource for Button Hover Effect Disable.

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonWithoutHover" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Border Name="border" 
                            BorderThickness="0"                                                        
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

And Add this to wpf window XAML

```
<Canvas >
            <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="DarkBlue" Canvas.Left="307" Canvas.Top="65">
            <DockPanel Canvas.Left="115" Canvas.Top="30">
                <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonWithoutHover}" BorderThickness="0" DockPanel.Dock="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="28" Width="23">
                    <Button.Background>
                        <ImageBrush  ImageSource="Images/User.png" Stretch="None" AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Center" />
                    </Button.Background>
                </Button>
                <TextBox FontSize="20"  BorderThickness="0" Height="28" Width="115" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent"/>
            </DockPanel>
            </Border>           
        </Canvas>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at Asryael's answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927364/wpf-textbox-with-image). 
It solves a similar issue without having to edit any templates.
Asryael's solution does require some extra styling.

You could also try the following, it simply adds some padding:

[image: Preview]

```
<TextBox Padding="16,2" Width="115" Height="28">
    <TextBox.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/User.png" Stretch="None" AlignmentX="Left"/>
    </TextBox.Background>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: You'll have to do some style editing to make it look prettier. You'll have to remove the Button hover effects and background. Same with the TextBox background and put any background/border styling on the DockPanel.

Comment: Oh! your updated answer is very nice. If i know this in the morning itself, it saves my hole day. but now I know How to add button in Textbox :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with Dock Panel as bellow

```
 <DockPanel>
     <Button BorderThickness="0" DockPanel.Dock="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Right"    Height="28" Width="25" Margin="200,10,10,10">     
      </Button>
     <TextBox Text="User" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent" Height="28" Width="200" Margin="-80,10,10,10"/>
   </DockPanel>
```

This may help you