# Customize WPF Toolkit autocompletebox

Tags: wpf, autocomplete, wpftoolkit

WPF Toolkit library has Autocompletebox control.
1. How to place an icon at the left of its Textbox part?
2. How to add shadow to the borders of the suggestions popup?
Changing TextBoxStyle property does not give any results.

```
<!-- xmlns:extendedControls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit" -->
<extendedControls:AutoCompleteBox>
  <extendedControls:AutoCompleteBox.TextBoxStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="20,0,0,0" />
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/img.png" Stretch="None" AlignmentX="Left" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
  </extendedControls:AutoCompleteBox.TextBoxStyle>
</extendedControls:AutoCompleteBox>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Autocompletebox have got a property : TextBoxStyle where you can chose the style of the textbox.
Or you can do that in the property Style like that :

```
    <UserControl.Resources>

        <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="TextboxStyle2">
            <Setter Property="MaxLength" Value="74" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="300" />
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="controls:AutoCompleteBox" x:Key="TextBoxStyle">
            <Setter Property="TextBoxStyle" Value="{StaticResource TextboxStyle2}" />
            <Setter Property="IsTextCompletionEnabled" Value="True" />
        </Style>

    </UserControl.Resources>

/*...*/

 <controls:AutoCompleteBox Name="Titre" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"/>
```

But i don't know how to add the shadow. Try the others properties. =)

**Edit :**
To change background, there is already some tutoriels. 
[how to separate the background image in wpf textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19700638/how-to-separate-the-background-image-in-wpf-textbox)

Exemple :

```
 <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="TextboxStyle2">
        <Setter Property="MaxLength" Value="74" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="300" />
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="../../../Ressources/Icones/Find_5650.ico" Stretch="None" AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Top" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: How to place an icon at the left of its Textbox part? Looks like I can't do it with TextBoxStyle property.

Comment: It works fine. There is already some exemples : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19700638/how-to-separate-the-background-image-in-wpf-textbox (i edited to show you)

Comment: It works fine for Textbox element, but not for AutocompleteBox. I've added my code to the post. Is it possible, that it can't be customized and I should write my own autocompelete textbox?