# Create something like textbox with icon/image contained

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, styling

I want to make something like this:

[image]

So it looks like textbox, its possible to write in the center so it is textbox acctualy, but on the left side there is icon of magnifier and on the right side there is icon of keyboard, but that looks like its all one control!

So guys, could anyone help me to create this?

Is it wrong if I do next thing:

[image]

**Or It is more correct to create Grid with 3 columns?**

> First Column would contain magnifier icon
>
> Second Column would contain textbox
>
> Third Column would contain keyboard icon

Or there is third way that I'm not aware of and that one is better than this 2 solutions I suggest.

Thanks a lot!
This community is the best!

Comment: Take a look to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927364/wpf-textbox-with-image

Comment: I have found this article that may help you. https://davidowens.wordpress.com/2009/02/18/wpf-search-text-box/

Answer (score 1):

> Or It is more correct to create Grid with 3 columns?

Yes, this would be better if the TextBox in the middle doesn't have a fixed width as a StackPanel doesn't measure its child elements.

You could add a Grid with 3 columns to a UserControl and bind the properties of the elements to dependency properties of the UserControl:

**UserControl1.xaml:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             x:Name="uc">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="20" Height="20" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=uc}" />
        <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="{Binding ImageSource, ElementName=uc}" Width="20" Height="20" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**UserControl1.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl4));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ImageSource", typeof(Uri), typeof(UserControl4));

    public Uri ImageSource
    {
        get { return (Uri)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<local:UserControl1 Text="..." ImageSource="Images/screen.png" />
```

Comment: Did you try this out or what happened?