# How to put an image inside the text box like an icon in c# xaml.cs?

Tags: c#, xaml

I want to take image in textbox like an icon n windows store app.

Like this:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF textbox with image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927364/wpf-textbox-with-image)

Comment: Thanks, But text is overlapping so what is the solution of this issue?

Comment: @Daniyal What text is overlapping what, where? Show us the code where you have the problem.

Comment: <TextBox Width="380" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Foreground="WhiteSmoke" BorderBrush="Transparent" >
     <TextBox.Background>
       <ImageBrush ImageSource="/icon/user_login.png" AlignmentX="Left" Stretch="None"></ImageBrush>
     </TextBox.Background>
 </TextBox>

Comment: i just did the same thing but the text show  above the icon.

Comment: If you do it the way I see described, just add a left padding to the TextBox to force the text to the side of the image. Personally though what I do is make a quick custom template with a 2 column grid with image in first column and its source template bound to Tag property so I can pass in different paths at the instance level, and the contentpresenter in the second column to ensure consistent display.